# php foreach from each item add tr

Tags: php, mysql

I have data array products

i try view

```
<table>
<?php foreach($products as $object): ?>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="center"><?php echo $object->name;?></th>

        <?php if ($object->id%1 == 0):?>
            <tr>
                <th class="center">Count</th>
                <th class="center">Price</th>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>


    </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

but i want other output view like this:
[image]

I have regions array from database to

Comment: can you give example of where the values beside name come from? what is the fourth row?

Comment: array product1=>array('name'=>'product1', 'count'=>0, 'price'=>5) i can't realize this fourth rows

Comment: `if ($object->id%1 == 0)` always returns true

Comment: yes after each iteration it add tr elements

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question but here is my answer for what i think you are after

```
<?php

// IGNORE THIS IS JUST BUILDING PRODUCTS

$product = new stdclass();
$product->name = 'Product 1';
$product->id = 1;
$product->count = 3;
$product->price = 4;

$products[] = $product;

$product = new stdclass();
$product->name = 'Product 2';
$product->id = 2;
$product->count = 1;
$product->price = 7;

$products[] = $product;

$product = new stdclass();
$product->name = 'Product 3';
$product->id = 3;
$product->count = 5;
$product->price = 3;

$products[] = $product;

$region = new stdclass();
$region->name = 'Region 1';

$regions[] = $region;

$region = new stdclass();
$region->name = 'Region 2';

$regions[] = $region;
?>

<style>
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

th 
{
    background: #ccc;
}

td
{
    width: 100px;
}

.center 
{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

<table>
<tr>
<th class="center" rowspan="2" >Regions</th>
<?php foreach( $products as $product ): ?>
<th colspan="2" class="center"><?php echo $product->name; ?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>

<tr>
<?php foreach( $products as $product ): ?>
<th class="center">Count</th><th class="center">Price</th>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>

<?php foreach( $regions as $region ): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $region->name; ?></td>
<?php foreach( $products as $product ): ?>
<td><?php echo $product->count; ?></td><td><?php echo $product->price; ?></td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

This will result with
[image]

Comment: sorry i want to do with parts full output view with regions on img

Comment: you beat me to it. this is the only way to keep all the data in one table is to loop through the $products array 3 times. The only other way would be to form one table per product and then use CSS to float them left.

Comment: @user3100681 your comments does not make any sense to me. Can you possibly reword it better?

Comment: i have two tables one regions, products. region(id, region_name), products(id, count, price, region_id)

Comment: Can you post some actual real example and a dummy example of the table you are trying to make?

Comment: I have changed the above answer - is that what you are looking for?